# why does the result of this recursive function in java is like that

Tags: java, function, recursion

```java
1. static void h2(int n){
2.        if(n<2)
3.            h2(n+1);
4.        System.out.print(n+" ");
5.        if(n<2)
6.            h2(n+1);
7. }
```

the function `h2()` is a recursive function
if I give `n=0` the result of this function is : `2 1 2 0 2 1 2` 
can someone explain to me how does this function work ? 
and what I wanna know also is next ==> for example in line `3` when the function `h2(n+1);` is called does the code continue to the next line and print the value on `n` or it goes and start over the function again ?

I added some print so I can see what happen :

```java
1. static void h2(int n){
2.        int i=0;
3.        if(n<2){
4.            System.out.println("i="+(++i)+" first n="+n+" ");
5.            h2(n+1);
6.        }
7.        System.out.println("i="+(++i)+" n="+n);
8.        if(n<2){
9.            System.out.println("\ni="+(++i)+" second n="+n+" ");
10.            h2(n+1);
11.       }
12. }
```

and this is the output of this code :

```
i=1 first n=0 
i=1 first n=1 
i=1 n=2
i=2 n=1

i=3 second n=1 
i=1 n=2
i=2 n=0

i=3 second n=0 
i=1 first n=1 
i=1 n=2
i=2 n=1

i=3 second n=1 
i=1 n=2
```

Comment: The downvotes are likely because you posted the code as an image. Don't do that. [Edit] your question to add the code as text to the question (preferably a [mre]), formatted in a code block. It would also be good to explain _why_ you think only `2` should be printed when the initial value of `n` is `0`.

Comment: Please review [ask] and [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I did some changes hope it's acceptable right now

Comment: There are things you can do to help visualize the code flow - for example, use a debugger and step through the code line by line; or maybe add "in" and "out" statements at the start and end of the method (e.g. `System.out.print("in ");` and `System.out.print("out ");`. Or even just write out the recursion levels and values of `n` with pencil and paper. Also, read different people's explanations (e.g [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55130777/how-does-recursion-actually-work-in-java)). You will find the approach which makes it "click" for you.

Comment: The `h2(n+1)` is what makes the function recursive. Though it does not cause the function to "start over". That implies you're in the _same_ function call. You're not. A new stack frame was allocated and the `h2` function is invoked with the new input argument (`n+1`). Eventually, if the recursion is implemented correctly, the recursive call to `h2` will _return_ and the function will continue as normal. It may help to trace the execution of the original call `h2(0)` by hand. Reason it out step-by-step (i.e., line-by-line) so you can see exactly what is happening.

Comment: A recursive method call is exactly like any other method call.  It does its work, then carries on with whatever line is next.  In this particular case, `h2(2)` prints `2`, because both `if` conditions come out false.  But `h2(1)` calls `h2(2)`, then prints `1`, then calls `h2(2)` again.  So you get `2 1 2`.  And `h2(0)` calls `h2(1)`, then prints `0`, then calls `h2(1)` again, which is why you get the result that you do.  I don't understand why anyone thought this question needed additional details or clarity; it seems perfectly clear to me.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I stil don't get it, can you please explain it line by line when it starts with `n=0` and so on...

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to explain in the limited space of the comments section.  But like I said, `h2(0)` calls `h2(1)` on line 3 of your original listing, then prints `0` on line 4, then calls `h2(1)` again, on line 6.  So if you know what `h2(1)` does, you can figure out what `h2(0)` does.  And because `h2(1)` calls `h2(2)`, then prints `1`, then calls `h2(2)` again; once you know what `h2(2)` does, you can figure out what `h2(1)` does.  But that's easy, because `h2(2)` just prints `2`.  And in your particular program, that will happen a total of 4 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a test application to show you the trace of the program's execution (requires Java 11 due to the use of [`String#repeat(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int))):

```java
public class Main {

  private static int depth;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    foo(0);
  }

  public static void foo(int n) {
    printDebug("Invoked foo(" + n + ")");

    if (n < 2) {
      printDebug("Recursively call foo(" + n + " + 1)");
      depth++;
      foo(n + 1);
      depth--;
      printDebug("Returned from recursive call of foo(" + n + " + 1)");
    } else {
      printDebug("Skip recursive call");
    }


    // this is the 'System.out.print(n + " "); line'
    printDebug("PRINT VALUE OF n AND A SPACE (n=" + n + ")");

    if (n < 2) {
      printDebug("Recursively call foo(" + n + " + 1)");
      depth++;
      foo(n + 1);
      depth--;
      printDebug("Returned from recursive call of foo(" + n  + " + 1)");
    } else {
      printDebug("Skip recursive call");
    }
  }

  private static void printDebug(String msg) {
    System.out.println("    ".repeat(depth) + msg);
  }
}
```

The recursive function was renamed to `foo` and was slightly modified to accommodate debug statements. When you run the above, the output will be:

```
Invoked foo(0)
Recursively call foo(0 + 1)
    Invoked foo(1)
    Recursively call foo(1 + 1)
        Invoked foo(2)
        Skip recursive call
        PRINT VALUE OF n AND A SPACE (n=2)
        Skip recursive call
    Returned from recursive call of foo(1 + 1)
    PRINT VALUE OF n AND A SPACE (n=1)
    Recursively call foo(1 + 1)
        Invoked foo(2)
        Skip recursive call
        PRINT VALUE OF n AND A SPACE (n=2)
        Skip recursive call
    Returned from recursive call of foo(1 + 1)
Returned from recursive call of foo(0 + 1)
PRINT VALUE OF n AND A SPACE (n=0)
Recursively call foo(0 + 1)
    Invoked foo(1)
    Recursively call foo(1 + 1)
        Invoked foo(2)
        Skip recursive call
        PRINT VALUE OF n AND A SPACE (n=2)
        Skip recursive call
    Returned from recursive call of foo(1 + 1)
    PRINT VALUE OF n AND A SPACE (n=1)
    Recursively call foo(1 + 1)
        Invoked foo(2)
        Skip recursive call
        PRINT VALUE OF n AND A SPACE (n=2)
        Skip recursive call
    Returned from recursive call of foo(1 + 1)
Returned from recursive call of foo(0 + 1)
```

The indent of each line shows the current depth of the recursive calls (more indent means deeper recursion). If you look at the order of the `PRINT VALUE OF n AND A SPACE (n=#)` lines, you'll see the output of the original recursive function will be:

```
2 1 2 0 2 1 2
```